# Sending a network request with a JSON header

Tags: android, xml, json

So, I have a method that sends a request to a webserver and grabs a response and stores it into a string.

My problem is that it returns XML by default, but I wan it to return JSON. The guy working on the server side said "it defaults to XML, but you can send the request with a JSON header, and it'll return that."

So, my question is, what do I have to do to request JSON data coming back instead of XML? (By the way, the guy on the server side isn't available to answer this question)

Thanks for the help

```
public class NetworkRequest {
private List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
private String URL;

public NetworkRequest(List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    this.nameValuePairs = nameValuePairs;
}

public String sendRequest() {
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return result;
}

public void setURL(String URL) {
    this.URL = URL;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add appropriate `Accept` header to your HttpPost:

```
httppost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));
```

or simply

```
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Are you sure it should be on the HttpPost? Wouldn't that try to send my data as JSON? Or am I mislead?

Comment: @Harry well, "Accept" header specifies the content-type the client would like to receive. Did you set the header prior to calling `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`?

Comment: Yep I certainly did. It is still returning as XML, no errors

Comment: @Harry I've just checked it in my environment - it definitely makes service return different content-type. Perhaps `"Accept", "*/json"` will make a difference? If not, all I can suggest is to find out which exact header is service expecting from the guy on the server side .

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll have to check with him. At least I know I've implemented it right. Thanks again

Comment: @Harry no problem, sorry it did not work as expected

Comment: @Harry oh, and just in case - here is a nice post further explaining headers in question - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-accept-and-content-type-http-headers